# How to keep NavLink active even though other links are clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'm trying to keep NavLink active even though any other links are clicked and navigated to it. Please refer to the code below for better clarity.

```
const LeftMenu = () => {
  return (
    <div className="side-navbar active-nav d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-column">
      <div>
        <ul className="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal small">
          <li className="nav-item-dropdown">
            <span className="mx-3">
              <NavLink to={companyShares} className="dropdown-nav-link px-3">
                COMPANY SHARES
              </NavLink>
            </span>
          </li>

          <li className="nav-item-dropdown">
            <span className="mx-3">
              <NavLink to={companyTech} className="dropdown-nav-link px-3">
                COMPANY TECH
              </NavLink>
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When clicked on button in a page, navigates to another screen, the side menu loses active background color. My intention is to make it active, whatever other links are clicked. What could be the best solution?

Please use username and password as 'test' to enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other route is related with your current parent (sidebar) route, make sure other route follows the parent route.

Eg: In you project. parent routes are

```
/companyShare
/companyTech
```

Now, if you are going to some other route inside /companyTech route, it has to start with /companyTech.

In your case, it is

```
/companyTech/techDetails     instead of /techDetails
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response... how can we keep background color even though the parent route isn't added?

Comment: You can't do that directly with Navlink. You'll have to manage it with states.
Like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-mountain-rxejp1?file=/src/pages/left-menu/LeftMenu.js

Comment: Perfect solution bro

Comment: This is what I was expecting... Thanks again